# how to use multiple paper-drawer-panel in polymer just like on polymer elements website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I was trying to make to paper-panel-drawer, one in left another on right (force-narrow) just like in the image below

[image]

I tried using nested paper-panel-drawer, but the one menu button open/closes the both drawer, i can't figure out where and how to place the trigger buttons, i  tried something like this:

```
      <paper-drawer-panel>
           <paper-header-panel drawer>
              <paper-toolbar><div>Application</div></paper-toolbar>
              <div> Drawer content... </div>
           </paper-header-panel>

           <paper-drawer-panel drawer force-narrow right-drawer>
               <paper-header-panel drawer>
                   <paper-toolbar>
                      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                      <div>Title</div>
                   </paper-toolbar>
                   <div> drawer2 content... </div>
              </paper-header-panel>

              <paper-header-panel>
                   <paper-toolbar>
                      <paper-icon-button icon="menu-vert" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                   </paper-toolbar>
                   <div> main content
                   </div>
             </paper-header-panel>
         </paper-drawer-panel>
     </paper-drawer-panel>
```

please help ?

Update:
Tried Günter Zöchbauer suggestions, and got following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Parts outside of the drawer have to get "main" attribute. It takes a little bit of juggling to assign main and drawer right.
See slightly changed code below (also removed force-narrow) to make it right drawer visible.

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
        <paper-toolbar><div>Application</div></paper-toolbar>
        <div> Drawer content... </div>
    </paper-header-panel>

    <paper-drawer-panel main right-drawer>
        <paper-header-panel drawer>
            <paper-toolbar>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                <div>Title</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <div> drawer2 content... </div>
        </paper-header-panel>

        <paper-header-panel main>
            <paper-toolbar>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu-vert" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <div>main content</div>
        </paper-header-panel>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It seems 2 drawers at once is not supported.
What is possible is to use one drawer and show it right **or** left but not both at the same time.
There is support to style them differently which should allow to show different content depending on which side the drawer actually is.

**Old**

I don't think nesting drawer panels can work.
Just removing the wrapping drawer panel should do it though.
The placing of the toggle buttons should be fine.

```
       <paper-header-panel drawer>
          <paper-toolbar><div>Application</div></paper-toolbar>
          <div> Drawer content... </div>
       </paper-header-panel>

       <paper-drawer-panel drawer force-narrow right-drawer>
           <paper-header-panel drawer>
               <paper-toolbar>
                  <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                  <div>Title</div>
               </paper-toolbar>
               <div> drawer2 content... </div>
          </paper-header-panel>

          <paper-header-panel>
               <paper-toolbar>
                  <paper-icon-button icon="menu-vert" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
               </paper-toolbar>
               <div> main content
               </div>
         </paper-header-panel>
       </paper-drawer-panel>
```

Comment: i didn't get you, can you please suggest required changes via code ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure if two `header-panels` within one `paper-drawer-panel` are supposed to work though.

Comment: hey thanks, i tried it , bit didn't work. i can't attach screenshot in comments

Answer (score 0):

this will be an alternative method, give #id to each paper-drawer & use javascript functions to control toggling instead of `paper-drawer-toggle`

```
drawerToggle: function() {
    if (this.$.drawer.narrow && this.$.drawer.getBoundingClientRect().width < parseInt(this.$.drawer.responsiveWidth)) {
        this.$.drawer.togglePanel();
    } else {
        this.$.drawer.forceNarrow = !this.$.drawer.forceNarrow;
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/winedi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

I just found custom elements 'paper-multidrawer-panel' on github

https://github.com/WoodyWoodsta/paper-multidrawer-panel

Here is sample html adapted from starter kit

```
<paper-multidrawer-panel force-narrow>
    <paper-scroll-header-panel left-drawer>
        <paper-toolbar>
            <span class="menu-name">Menu</span>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <paper-menu class="app-menu">
            <a href="#">
                <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
                <span>Home</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <iron-icon icon="info"></iron-icon>
                <span>Users</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon>
                <span>Contact</span>
            </a>
        </paper-menu>
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    <paper-scroll-header-panel right-drawer>
        <paper-toolbar>
            <span class="menu-name">Options</span>
        </paper-toolbar>
        Options Contents
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    <paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" condenses keep-condensed-header>
        <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
            <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-multidrawer-toggle-left></paper-icon-button>
            <span class="space"></span>
            <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="search" paper-multidrawer-toggle-right></paper-icon-button>
            <div class="middle middle-container">
                <div class="app-name">Polymer Starter Kit</div>
            </div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div class="content">
            Main Content
        </div>
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>
</paper-multidrawer-panel>
```